# Availability calculation using PromQL

Tags: prometheus, health-monitoring, promql, kube-apiserver

I'm going to monitor my Kubernetes cluster availability.  Prometheus server scraping `kube-apiserver` metrics and calculate availability percent according to `kube-apiserver` pods availability. Sometime `kube-apiserver` pods down and Prometheus server is not able to scrape at all and sometime pods are up and running and also serving requests but due to network connectivity or any other reason Prometheus server can not scrape metrics.
Is there any way to use PromQL to ignore no values? Or the better way to calculate Kubernetes cluster availability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manage 'no data', I found [this](https://medium.com/@Nklya/promql-how-to-return-0-instead-of-no-data-9e49f7ccb80d) article and helped me to write my query:

```
clamp_max(sum by (cluster) (up{component="kube-apiserver"}),1) or on() vector(0)
```

Using `or on() vector(0)` to the end of your expression. It will return 0 if the metric expression does not return anything.